# How to extend HTML of an existing site via JavaScript or similar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, amazon-web-services, varnish

I want to add a bit of extra HTML to an existing site based on a REST API call response.

Specifically, www.arbookfind.com lets you search for kids school books with an "AR" test. (My son has to read a certain number of books at a level.) It has a link to amazon.com if you find a book you want to buy. However I would like to know if available for Kindle (most are not). Right now I have to click the Amazon link, check the page, go back and try next one - it can take 10 tries to find one available on the Kindle. Painful!

I was after ideas of the easiest way to do this. That is, without touching the arbookfind.com web site, can I add some JavaScript (jQuery) to all the returned HTML pages. The JavaScript will look in the returned page for each book, fire off a Amazon ItemSearch query (?) to see if available on Kindle, then inject a HTML link to the Kindle book on Amazon. I can learn how to write the JavaScript - I am just after some pointers for the easiest way to augment the current site.

That way I can use the current arbookfind.com site to find a book, but it is faster for me to identify which books are available on Kindle without manually trying each link by hand.

E.g. a web browser plugin that runs some javaScript on each returned page?  A varnish proxy with some smart logic to fiddle pages on the way through?  A PHP app acting like as a proxy server?  Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access Kindle Highlights (API?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374045/how-to-access-kindle-highlights-api)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to have something like the chrome extension Tampermonkey.
It allows to add and manage userscripts for websites. Means, a javascript "snippet" which is added to websites maching specific patterns.